# Can Penrose tilings generate regular polyhedra?

Tags: polyhedra, tiling

Physicist Roger Penrose discovered several pairs of polygons that can each tile the infinite plane aperiodically (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_tiling). Is there way to fold such a tiling, or a finite strip of such tiling, or a finite regular pentagonal subset of such a tiling, so as to form a regular but aperiodic polyhedron? There would clearly be many follow-on questions if this were possible, but they are beyond my ability to imagine. This question was stimulated by the very interesting video  [there are 48 regular polyhedra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hjRvZYkAgA).

Comment: Make a cube out of jelly babies (vertices) and cocktail sticks (Edges) ... Now squidge it about. If by regular you mean, only one type of vertex type, then the answer is no ... If you relax this to mean, the faces are Penrose kites, then we would need to do a bit of $3$d geometry to check the dihedral angles worked out. ... and the answer would be probably.

Comment: This question is quite vague as it is. Let me ask you some questions which might help you to make it more precise. 1. Do you want a polyhedron whose sides are *exactly* those penrose tiles? Or do you not care about the exact angles and lengths? There are some polyhedra with identical rhombic faces that are not "periodic" (e.g. [this one](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinski_dodecahedron)). 2. what do you mean by "regular"? Usually *regular* has a very precise meaning, so that there are exactly 5 regular (convex) polyhedra, and no more. 3. What do you mean by "polyhedron"? ...

Comment: ... Should they be convex? Without self-intersections? Without holes? And just a note on the video: I think this video makes a strange point. It tries to show that there are (surprisingly?!) more such polyhedra by widening the definition more and more. But is it really surprising that there is more of something if I am intentionally vague and refuse to state what I am actually try to enumerate?